# how to create a scrolling list with angular material cdk

Tags: angular, scroll, angular-material, scrollview, angular-cdk

I have a mat dialog component contain a list of available language in my app dosplayed as list, and I'm trying to create a scrollable element instead, the dialog is opened from a main navbar with an event click, i got this error :

> main-navbar.component.html:9 ERROR Error: Error:
> cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport requires the "itemSize" property to be
> set.

here is my code :

*language-dialog.html*

```
<div class="language-dialog">
  <div class="content">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="48" class="example-viewport">
      <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let language of languages">
        <div class="language-column" (click)="switchLang(language.code)" (keypress)="switchLang(language.code)" tabindex="0">
          <span class="flag-icon {{ language.flagClass }}"></span>
          {{ language.countryName }}
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
  </div>
</div>
```

*language-dialog.ts:*

```
import {Component, Inject, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core'
import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core"
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material/dialog"

interface Language {
  code: string
  flagClass: string
  countryName: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-language-dialog',
  templateUrl: './language-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./language-dialog.component.scss']
})

export class LanguageDialogComponent implements OnDestroy{

  selectedLanguage: Language = { code: '', flagClass: '', countryName: '' }
  languages: Language[] =  [
    { code: 'en', flagClass: 'fi fi-gb-eng', countryName: 'United Kingdom' },
    { code: 'fr', flagClass: 'fi fi-fr', countryName: 'France' },
    { code: 'bg', flagClass: 'fi fi-bg', countryName: 'България' },
    { code: 'cs', flagClass: 'fi fi-cz', countryName: ' Česká' },
    { code: 'da', flagClass: 'fi fi-dk', countryName: 'Danmark' },
    { code: 'de', flagClass: 'fi fi-de', countryName: 'Deutschland' },
    { code: 'el', flagClass: 'fi fi-gr', countryName: 'Ελλάδα' },
    { code: 'es', flagClass: 'fi fi-es', countryName: 'España' },
    { code: 'et', flagClass: 'fi fi-ee', countryName: 'Eesti' },
    { code: 'fi', flagClass: 'fi fi-fi', countryName: 'Suomi' },
    { code: 'ga', flagClass: 'fi fi-ie', countryName: 'Éire' },
    { code: 'hr', flagClass: 'fi fi-hr', countryName: 'Hrvatska' },
    { code: 'hu', flagClass: 'fi fi-hu', countryName: 'Magyarország' },
    { code: 'it', flagClass: 'fi fi-it', countryName: 'Italia' },
    { code: 'lt', flagClass: 'fi fi-lt', countryName: 'Lietuva' },
    { code: 'lv', flagClass: 'fi fi-lv', countryName: 'Latvija' },
    { code: 'mt', flagClass: 'fi fi-mt', countryName: 'Malta' },
    { code: 'nl', flagClass: 'fi fi-nl', countryName: 'Nederland' },
    { code: 'pl', flagClass: 'fi fi-pl', countryName: 'Polska' },
    { code: 'pt', flagClass: 'fi fi-pt', countryName: 'Portugal' },
    { code: 'ro', flagClass: 'fi fi-ro', countryName: 'România' },
    { code: 'sk', flagClass: 'fi fi-sk', countryName: 'Slovensko' },
    { code: 'sl', flagClass: 'fi fi-si', countryName: 'Slovenija' },
    { code: 'sv', flagClass: 'fi fi-se', countryName: 'Sverige' },
  ]
  languageRows: Language[][] = []

  constructor(
    public translateService: TranslateService,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<LanguageDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { selectedLanguage: Language },
  ) {
    this.selectedLanguage = data.selectedLanguage

  }

  switchLang(language: string): void {
    this.translateService.use(language)
    const newSelectedLanguage = this.languages.find(lang => lang.code === language)
    this.dialogRef.close(newSelectedLanguage)
  }
```

*main-navbar.html*

```
<mat-toolbar class="main-toolbar" color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row class="mat-elevation-z6 navbar-padding" fxLayoutAlign="space-between" >
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" >
      <img alt="LGCF Logo" src="assets/imgs/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center">
      <img class="logo ue-logo" alt="eu Logo" src="assets/imgs/eu.jpg" />

      <button mat-button (click)="openLanguageSelectionPopup()" class="language-button" >
        <span class="flag-icon {{ selectedLanguage.flagClass }}"></span>
        <span class="code-ln">{{ selectedLanguage.code }}</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: Did you try `[itemSize]="48"`?

Comment: @Eldar ok , error fixed now but still see nothing in my dialog !

Comment: Did you implement the definition of the example-viewport class? Because I know this is how it is used in the cdk docs, and maybe you just copied it without defining it in the scss file. 

I managed to show results using your code in stackblitz, by simply defining the css classes